# Widgets / Panel create javascript opensource library

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Anybody can help me in finding out the any opensource javascript related framework/library(s), which is having the below functionality.

To create a dashboard/page with 4 panels/widgets. 
 
Each    widget/panel will load aync/independently with different  data/content.
 
Any one widget/panel can auto update after    particular period of time.
 
Dynamically removing/adding    widget/panels from the dashboard/screen.

Thanks,
nRk

Comment: Take a look at this http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comment.Bootstrap give layout with column & rows. But is there any framework to create widget like things.

Comment: this url contains good examples about panels/widget: https://github.com/DataTorrent/malhar-dashboard-webapp